# Why are titles sometimes placed in the middle of a newspaper article?

Tags: writing

In a newspaper I'm reading (环球时报), there are multiple articles in which the title appears somewhere in the middle of the text.  One example is:

> [image: A newspaper article with the title 菅义伟首次外访为何选东南亚 appearing in the middle of the main text]
> <sub>(click for unannotated version; other examples: 美人员现身台雷达站威胁有多大 ([newspaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xslHd.jpg); [online](http://www.fx361.com/page/2020/1016/7099724.shtml)) and 全球确诊超四千万，欧美疫情恶劣 and 英国放狼话逼欧盟妥协 ([newspaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDmk8.jpg); not found online))</sub>

As we see in the article above, the title 菅义伟首次外访为何选东南亚 and author name 陈友骏 appear in the middle of the text, while the text starts at the top-left corner beginning with 日本…….  (The electronic version is [here](https://opinion.huanqiu.com/article/40M8Vyv0E5C) where the title is at the top.)

I don't understand the logic behind this at all: it has taken me a long time to realize that this happens.  I don't recall ever seeing this in an English-language newspaper, which makes me think there is some rationale which I'm unaware of.

**Question**: Why are titles sometimes placed in the middle of a newspaper article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps Chinese press is just more flexible in this particular respect. I searched and found [the following from a book](https://books.google.ae/books?id=wRhJ51jX0KEC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=%E6%8A%A5%E7%BA%B8%20%E6%A0%87%E9%A2%98%E6%94%BE%E5%9C%A8%E6%96%87%E7%AB%A0%E4%B8%AD%E9%97%B4&source=bl&ots=2gpZlhEmbc&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM7JeEx8fsAhWCs54KHXF3C70Q6AEwB3oECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%E6%8A%A5%E7%BA%B8%20%E6%A0%87%E9%A2%98%E6%94%BE%E5%9C%A8%E6%96%87%E7%AB%A0%E4%B8%AD%E9%97%B4&f=false):

> 标题可以插在文字中间,也可以对角设置,或放在文尾,或**分散在文中**等。但是，要注意标题与文章不能分离或错位。为了使标题既能突出又能活跃版面，在同一版面中应为不同的稿件设置标题的多种排列形式。

[Another article](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/2fea17186bd97f192279e9e2.html) says:

> Ⅰ 直题：报纸版面以直题为主。
>
> Ⅱ 横题：用以调节版面，通常至于四角，不宜横于版面中央
>
> Ⅲ 叠字题：可分直题横排和横题直排。
>
> Ⅳ 横直题：横直运用，即是运用眉题。
>
> Ⅴ 对角题：新闻集锦或花絮的标题，多方右上角及左下角。
>
> Ⅵ **包中题：标题放在文章中央，可避免顶题及调节版面均衡。**
>
> Ⅶ 分题：新闻内容长，非一个标题所能概括时，需要分题。
>
> Ⅷ 插题：即小标题。

It seems that titles can be put in a variety of places. They can even be put at the end of articles. People also try to apply different styles for titles on the same page, in order to avoid repetition, boost readability and get more balanced typography.

In particular 包中题 is given as the name for titles in the middle of articles. However, I searched and could not find much reference for this term, so I don't know how popular the term is.

Answer (score 1):

I worked in this field. In my experience, the title is never placed in the middle of an article because the function of a title is to lead the reader to the beginning of the article, telling them where to start reading.

The only explanation I can think of is for a stylistic reason. Maybe the previous article is too short and makes the two titles too close to each other.

In this case, the article must be framed so the reader would know where to start reading (under the top bar of the frame)

Comment: Renmin Ribao uses it but less often.
http://paper.people.com.cn/rmrb/html/2020-10/22/nbs.D110000renmrb_15.htm

Comment: Perhaps an asymmetrical title catches the eye better? Anything out of the ordinary usually solicits more curiosity as it did for 李蓓 ?